# Google Info window close button not working in mobile

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using the following code to create custom info window

```
function format(j,x,q,o,y,g,l,i,n,u){var nn="",uu="",mm=27,m=21,c="Tab2",d="",k="",v="",p="",t="",e="",b="",a="",f="",r,w=6,h=null,s=null;if(u.length==0){c="Tab4"}if(o!=null){if(o.indexOf("?")>0){o=o.substring(1,o.indexOf("?"))}}
y=replaceAll(y,'^','');g=replaceAll(g,'^','');l=replaceAll(l,'^','');y=replaceAll(y,"&amp;amp;","&");g=replaceAll(g,"&amp;amp;","&");l=replaceAll(l,"&amp;amp;","&");y=replaceAll(y,"&amp;","&");g=replaceAll(g,"&amp;","&");l=replaceAll(l,"&amp;","&");y=replaceAll(y,'\\','');g=replaceAll(g,'\\','');l=replaceAll(l,'\\','');
var yyy=replaceAll(y,"'","`");var ggg=replaceAll(g,"'","`");var lll=replaceAll(l,"'","`");y=replaceAll(y,"&quot;","\"");g=replaceAll(g,"&quot;","\"");l=replaceAll(l,"&quot;","\"");
if(y.length>m){v="<a style='cursor:pointer; color:#353535;' onmouseout='UnTip()' onmouseover=\"Tip('&lt;div class=&quot;leftBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;rightBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;midBgBuble&quot;&gt;"+yyy+"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')\"><b>"+y.substring(0,(m-4)).toUpperCase()+"...</b></a>";}else{d=y.toUpperCase();v="<b>"+d+"</b>"}
if(g.length>m){e="<a style='cursor:pointer; color:#353535;' onmouseout='UnTip()' onmouseover=\"Tip('&lt;div class=&quot;leftBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;rightBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;midBgBuble&quot;&gt;"+ggg+"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')\">"+g.substring(0,(m-4)).toUpperCase()+"...</a>";}else{p=g;e=p}
if(l.length>m){f="<a style='cursor:pointer; color:#353535;' onmouseout='UnTip()' onmouseover=\"Tip('&lt;div class=&quot;leftBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;rightBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;midBgBuble&quot;&gt;"+lll+"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')\">"+l.substring(0,(m-4)).toUpperCase()+"...</a>";}else{b=l;f=b}if(ie6){r="margin:-2px 7px 0 0;";w=5}else{if(ie7){r="margin: 2px 11px 0 0;"}else{if(moz||saf||op){r="margin:2px 10px 0 0;"}else{r="margin: 2px 11px 0 0;"}}}
if(u.length!=0){if(u.length>mm){uu="";}else{uu="";}s='<tr><td style="font:normal 10px Arial; color:#353535;padding:0 0 10px 0;" align="left"><table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td></td><td style="padding:0 0 0 6px;">'+uu+"</td></tr></table></td></tr>"}else{s="<tr><td></td></tr>"}
if(n.length!=0){if(n.length>mm){nn="<a style='cursor:pointer; color:#353535; text-decoration:none;' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=\"javascript:"+c+"('Tab3.aspx?locationid="+i+"');UnTip();\" onmouseout='UnTip()' onmouseover=\"Tip('&lt;div class=&quot;leftBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;rightBuble&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;midBgBuble&quot;&gt;"+n+"&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;')\">"+n.substring(0,mm-3)+"...</a>";}else{nn="<a title='"+n+"' href='javascript:void(0)' onclick=\"javascript:"+c+"('Tab3.aspx?locationid="+i+"');\" style='text-decoration:none;'>"+n+"</a>";}h='<tr><td style="font:normal 10px Arial; color:#353535; padding:0 0 2px 0;"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td><img src="images/arrow.PNG" alt=""/></td><td style="padding:0 0 0 6px;"><a title="'+n+'" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="javascript:'+c+"('Tab3.aspx?locationid="+i+'\')" style="text-decoration:none;">'+nn+"</a></td></tr></table></td></tr>"}else{h="<tr><td></td></tr>"}return'<div style="width: 202px; height:238px; padding:4px 3px 0 3px; background-image: url(images/map_popwindow.PNG); background-repeat: no-repeat; font:normal 11px/14px Arial; color:#353535;" class="estyle2"><table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td colspan="5" align="left" valign="top" style="padding:0 0 0 1px;" ><div align="center" id="divPlayer1" name="divPlayer1"><div id="imageName1" name="imageName1"><img src="'+q+'"/></div></div><img src="images/map_closebuttom.PNG" alt="" style="z-index:99; position:absolute; top:1px; right:0px; border:solid 3px #fff; cursor:pointer;'+r+'" onclick="javascript:void closeInfo();" /></td> </tr><tr><td style="width: 21px; height: 30px; padding:3px 0 0 12px;"  valign="top"><img src="'+o+'" style="border:none; width: 21px; height: 27px;" alt="" /></td><td style="width: 151px; padding:0 3px 0 9px;"><table style="width: 100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td style="padding:9px 0 5px 0;">'+v+"</td></tr><tr><td>"+e+'</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:1px 0 6px 0;">'+f+"</td></tr>"+h+s+"</table></td></tr></table></div>"};
```

and the following code to popup the window

```
function b(k,L,M,K){var J=new GMarker(k,L);GEvent.addListener(J,"click",function(){map.panTo(k);ew.openOnMarker(J,M);});if(K==true){map.addOverlay(J);ew.openOnMarker(J,M)}return J}for(var D=0;D<q;D++){var r=new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);r.image=baseURL+"images/mme_dealer_marker"+f[D][0]+".png";r.shadow="";r.iconSize=new GSize(29,56);r.iconAnchor=new GPoint(0,58);f[D][9]=replaceAll(f[D][9],"&amp;","&");f[D][9]=replaceAll(f[D][9],"&quot;","\"");markerOptions={icon:r,clickable:true,title:f[D][0]+". "+f[D][9]};var v=format(f[D][1],f[D][2],f[D][3],f[D][4],f[D][5],f[D][6],f[D][7],f[D][8],x,H);var B=new GLatLng(f[D][1],f[D][2]);if(D==(p-1)){map.addOverlay(b(B,markerOptions,v,true))}else{map.addOverlay(b(B,markerOptions,v,false))}}}}
```

The detailed javascript can be downloaded by saving the following url

http://m3imobile.mydiamondlink.net/m3imobile/list.aspx?city=berlin&postcode=&radius=30&point=52.519171,13.4060912&Services=&pageno=1&flag=0

All these working fine in desktop browser but the close button not working in Mobile browsers.
Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

This can be tested in mobile by using the above URL

Comment: The built-in javascript interpreter in my head returned an error. (Please: format your code!)

Comment: Presumably this is Google Maps API Version 2 (since you use GEvent). Please add the right tags. Please add the right tags to indicate which mobile platforms experience the issue. And please format your code.